# Log a user in using a generated Anonymous Login ID

Tags: firebase

I am writing an Android application and I am trying to log users in anonymously so they don't have to go through any sort of registration process. I am storing their anonymous user ID in shared preferences, and when the application opens, I am trying to log them in based on that user ID. I am trying to figure out the correct way to do this, as there doesn't seem to be an auth function that just takes in a UID. Currently I have it using auth(), but I don't feel like that is correct.

Here is some sample code:

```
String userID = getUserID();

    if(userID.equals("NOT_FOUND")) {
        ref.authAnonymously(new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
                //successful authentication
                //save auth data
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                        "USER_ID", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String id = authData.getUid();
                prefs.edit().putString("USER_ID", id).commit();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                //unsuccessful authentication
            }
        });
    } else {
        ref.auth(userID, new Firebase.AuthListener() {
           ...
```

Answer (score 6):

You're creating a new authentication session each and every time you invoke `FirebaseRef.authAnonymously(...)`. This method only needs to be invoked once, after which the user will authenticated upon page refreshes. Also note that you do not need to call `FirebaseRef.auth()` again once restarting the application, as that piece is automatically handled for you.

If you'd like to check for the current authentication state of the user, and *only then* create a new authentication session if the user is not currently authenticated, use the synchronous accessor for authentication state `FirebaseRef.getAuth()`.

Lastly, once you create an anonymous authentication session, no new sessions may ever be created with the same uid. That session will live until your predefined session expiration time (configured in your account dashboard) or until your user logs out, after which that uid is permanently retired.

Comment: Okay, so I guess if I want a user to be able to log in again and have their data, I need to ask them register at least once?

Comment: If you want a user to be able to log out and then back in, or log in with the same account across multiple devices, you'll need to use an authentication method that has a credential tied to it (i.e. password, OAuth-token, etc.). We do not allow you to authenticate to the same anonymous auth. account multiple times because they have no credentials associated with them, and there is then no way to prevent users from authenticating as one another and spoofing others' accounts.

Comment: Rob, great answers. One follow up question. We love this anonymous login feature. I noticed that for Android, you store the uid, token in shared preference. So, can we assume that as long as user does not delete app, user will always be using that uid? I wish SDK provided API to sign in with specific uid so that we could be sure.

Comment: @andude That is correct. We don't let you lever re-authenticate an anonymous user though. You could do sign-in with a specific uid using custom token generation, but we don't allow this for anonymous auth because we don't have a good credential to use for it.