# How to prevent new anonymous authentication UID after browser refresh in Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I am using anonymous authentication in Firebase with Angular. The goal is to have one UID associated with a user until the browser is closed. I would like to use the same UID even if the page is refreshed. However, when I use the code below, a new UID and token is created every time a user refreshes the page. How do I prevent this from happening?

```
myApp.factory('fbAuth', function($firebaseAuth) {
var ref = new Firebase('https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com');

ref.authAnonymously(function (error, authData) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Login Failed!', error);
    } else {
        console.log('Authenticated successfully with payload:', authData);
    }
},
    {remember: 'sessionOnly'
    });
});

myApp.controller('ProjectListCtrl', function(Projects, fbAuth) {
var projectList = this;
projectList.projects = Projects;
});
```

Comment: See [Log a user in using a generated Anonymous Login ID](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26721502/879295). In short, you're throwing away the existing session every time you call `ref.authAnonymously()`.

Comment: @Rob DiMarco Thanks. Am having trouble figuring out how to combine the two (first determine whether auth exists; if not, auth anonymously). Insert this first? `var authData = ref.getAuth(); if (authData) {console.log('Authenticated user with uid:', authData.uid); } else {`

Comment: Sure, that would work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Log a user in using a generated Anonymous Login ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720714/log-a-user-in-using-a-generated-anonymous-login-id)

Comment: @Kato I think you're right that this is very similar to the referenced post. Should I delete this one?

Comment: Hey Ken. I wouldn't bother. It's a good question and worth asking; finding the old ones can be difficult (I happen to have seen every Firebase question since the beginning). It will probably get closed as a dup, which will only help others searching for similar terms as your title. Cheers.